# Creating Json from XAgent

Tags: java, json, xpages, projekktor

I'm trying to create some Json from an XPages "XAgent" using Java.  There's a particular format I'm trying to it and it uses an Integer as a key and I keep getting some errors that I don't understand.

Here's an example error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.String
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.outObject(JsonGenerator.java:202)
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.outLiteral(JsonGenerator.java:163)
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.outLiteral(JsonGenerator.java:142)
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator$Generator.toJson(JsonGenerator.java:138)
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator.toJson(JsonGenerator.java:64)
at com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator.toJson(JsonGenerator.java:49)

I'm trying to create JSon output like this:

```
[
  {
     // minimum 
     0:{src:'item_one_format_one.ext', type: 'video/...'}     
  },
  {
     // one content, multiple formats
     0:{src:'item_two_format_one.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     1:{src:'item_two_format_two.ext', type: 'video/...'}
  },
  {
     // one content, multiple formats, item specific config
     0:{src:'item_three_format_one.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     1:{src:'item_three_format_two.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     3:{src:'item_three_format_three.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     4:{src:'item_three_format_four.ext', type: 'video/...'},          
     config: {
        option1: value1,
        option2: value2
     }

]
```

Not it is multiple "objects" and the last one seems to be a combination of Integer and String for the key value.

Here is some code I tried and got working kinda of:

```
public String testList() throws JsonException, IOException {

        Integer count = 0;

        Map<String, Object> containerMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("A");


        TreeMap<String, String> stringMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        System.out.println("B");
        stringMap.put("One", "Value1");
        stringMap.put("Two", "Value2");
        System.out.println("C");

        containerMap.put("1", "One");
        count++;
        containerMap.put("2", "Two");
        count++;
        containerMap.put("3", "Three");

        System.out.println("D");

        String json = JsonGenerator.toJson(new JsonJavaFactory(), containerMap);
        System.out.println("E");
        return json;

    }
```

this code produces:

```
{
    "1": "Zero",
    "2": "One",
    "3": "Two"
}
```

Note the quotes for the key value.  I assume that's going to be a problem.  I was enable to get Integers in for the key. And I'm not sure how to mix Integers with String as seen in the 3rd object example.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Afaik Json keys must be Strings

Comment: I second that, the keys must be strings.
The 2nd JSON is correct, JSONLint is your friend: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Strings only?  hmm I didn't know that.  I've only ever really played with trying to hit this format for the Projekktor Project: http://www.projekktor.com/docs/playlists  and that shows the leading integers.  Maybe it'll work fine with the double quotes around the numbers.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It cannot be used an integer in this way:
{0: {...}}
The properties are supposed to be strings:
{"0": {...}}

Maybe you need an array instead:

`{
     // one content, multiple formats, item specific config
    videoList: [
     {src:'item_three_format_one.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     {src:'item_three_format_two.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     {src:'item_three_format_three.ext', type: 'video/...'},
     {src:'item_three_format_four.ext', type: 'video/...'}
    ],
    vidoConfig: {
        option1: value1,
        option2: value2
    }
}`

Regards,
Txemanu

Comment: Is that Java or SSJS?  That looks more like SSJS which I've done before and then I did "toJson()" to return the string.

Comment: I was just talking about json. Does not matter if it's generated with Java or SSJS.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gson. Saves you ton of headaches. Must be in a plug-in for security to work. Make a result class with collections and maps and whatever. Then have 2 lines:

```
   Gson g = new Gson();
   g.toJson(this);
```

There is a builder and a few annotations for options like pretty print or naming elements different from the variable names.

Pecked on glass at high altitude. Will contain typos.

Comment: Is there a GSon plugin on on OpenNTF? That's not something I know how to do myself.

Comment: Create a plug-in. Add the Gson jar. Define the classes to be reexported

Comment: So you have Verse installed on your server? The plugins contain Google’s Gson and Guava libraries